# How do I split cell contents that contain "=" the left part into column titles and the right into row values, using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Origin:

```
    0 1
    PASS AC=24;AF=1;AN=24;DP=39;ExcessHet=3.0103
    PASS AC=14;AF=1;AN=14;FS=0;MLEAC=2
```

What I want:

```
    0 AC AF AN DP ExcessHet FS MLEAC
    PASS 24 1 24 39 3.0103 NAN NAN
    PASS 14 1 14 NAN NAN 0 2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lXCg.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Format the question better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `str.split` `explode`, `unstack` and `concat`

```
m = df['1'].str.split(';').explode().str.split('=',expand=True)

m1 = m.groupby([m[0],m.index])[1].agg(list).apply(pd.Series).unstack(0)

m1.columns = m1.columns.get_level_values(1)

df1 = pd.concat([df,m1],axis=1).drop('1',axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df1)

          0  AC AF  AN   DP ExcessHet   FS MLEAC
0      PASS  24  1  24   39    3.0103  NaN   NaN
1      PASS  14  1  14  NaN       NaN    0     2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!